# $\frac{d}{dx}[\int_{2x^2}^6 \sin(y^3)dy]$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to evaluate the following:
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\int_{2x^2}^6 \sin(y^3)dy]$$

I'm really unsure as to how I'm supposed to evaluate these, I was thinking in the direction of well, what ever the outcome is, the upper bound is not going to stick around since that would just be a constant which you then differentiate, but for the lowerbound I was thinking it would just be $-sin((2x^2)^3)$ but that doesn't seem to be correct.

Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: 1. Why the minus sign? 2. Why the +C? 3. Don't forget the chain rule

Comment: Well you'd have $sin(6^3) - sin(2(x^2)^2)$? How would I apply the chain rule without knowing what it is I need to differentiate? @DavidP

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\color{blue}d}{dx}\int\cdots$?

Comment: @AndrewChin yeah sorry my mistake, corrected it.

Comment: Use `\sin`, not `sin`

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sin(x^3)$ and let $F(x)$ be an antiderivative of $f$, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} \int_{2x^2}^6 \sin(y^3) \,dy
&= \frac{d}{dx} \int_{2x^2}^6 f(y) \,dy
\overset{(*)}{=} \frac{d}{dx} \left[\,F(6) - F(2x^2) \,\right]\\
&= 0 - \tfrac{d (2x^2)}{dx} F'(2x^2) = - 4xf(2x^2)\\
&= -4x\sin(8 x^6)
\end{align*}

where (*) is the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: I don't quite understand how we can just take the derivative of $2x^2$ to evaluate that chain rule without knowing what the actual function is that came out of the integral..

Comment: The family of antiderivatives of $\sin(x^3)$ exist, even if we don't have a closed form for the function. By defining $F$ and $f$ in the way I have above, $F'(x) = f(x)$ and therefore $\frac{d}{dx} F(2x^2) = \frac{d}{dx}(2x^2) F'(2x^2) = 4x f(2x^2)$.

Comment: @user472288 sure, let $u=2x^2$

Comment: Theorems like the chain rule are very powerful, in part, because they apply broadly. The fact it can be applied to functions without explicit representation may make you uneasy, but it gives you a small glimmer at the power of these techniques.